# When will Firefox 55 be in the repos?

Tags: updates, firefox

So I'd like to have FF55. When will it be in the auto updater?

Moslty I'd like to know the process to update FireFox in the repos. Where can I follow this process?
I'd like to know, especially with the [big FF57](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/sneak-peek-firefox-photon-linux) upcoming on the horizon.

Comment: In due course. ...and why is FF55 related to FF57?

Comment: _In due course_ what do you mean by that? They are not related. But I'd like to understand the process a bit better.

Comment: Packages are tested before they get uploaded to the repositories. With FF, there is usually a gap of a few days or more if there are problems. So, after the testing is done, and a package is deemed stable, it is then uploaded. Ubuntu has two PPAs for Firefox testing: [mozilla-security](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)  and [firefox-next](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next).

Comment: @mikewhatever If you make this into a question I'll accept it. I'm mostly interested in the process

Comment: It started rolling out 2 days ago `(15/7/17)`. 
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/firefox-55-upgrade-finally-rolling-ubuntu-sure-update .
It would be nice to get a public discussion board and understand the considerations for the (acceptable, of course) delay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FF55 will be included in 17.04 but it is up to the Mozilla team when this happens (Or maybe it will be 56, 57, 58, 59 or 60. Depending how quick Mozilla releases the next version ;) )

Why the need to update it from the repositories? You can download and install it from the [official website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/). Unpack it in `/opt/`, start firefox from `/opt/`, lock it to the launcher and you use the latest version.

This took me literally seconds to do:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945244/when-will-firefox-55-be-in-the-repos#comment1501823_945244) (emphasis mine):

> Packages are tested before they get uploaded to the repositories. With FF, **there is usually a gap of a few days**, or more if there are problems. So, after the testing is done, and a package is deemed stable, it is then uploaded. Ubuntu has two PPAs for Firefox testing: [mozilla-security](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and [firefox-next](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next).

For more detailed information, you can compare the [release dates of past Firefox versions on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history) with the build dates of the [firefox package in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+publishinghistory). For example, in the current Ubuntu LTS (xenial), these are the dates corresponding to the last few Firefox versions:

```
Version | Release    | Launchpad build
--------+------------+----------------
56.0    | 2017-09-28 | 2017-10-04
55.0.2  | 2017-08-16 | 2017-10-02
54.0    | 2017-06-13 | 2017-08-15
53.0    | 2017-04-19 | 2017-05-11
52.0.2  | 2017-03-28 | 2017-04-20
```

(Note: I don't claim to know how this process unfolds, nor that these numbers are the most relevant ones; I'm merely collecting data points I was able to locate, hoping they can help others make an informed guess).